# Let $\frac {dx}{dt}=Ax+By,\frac {dy}{dt}=x,$ where $B<-1<A<0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across the following problem that says:

> Consider the pair of first order ordinary differential equations
>   $\frac {dx}{dt}=Ax+By,\frac {dy}{dt}=x,$ where $B<-1<A<0.$ Let $(x(t),y(t))$ be the solution of the above that satisfies  $(x(0),y(0))=(0,1).$ Then pick the correct statement:
>   $1.(x(t),y(t))=(0,1) \forall t \in \mathbb R$
>   $2.x(t)$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$
>   $3.y(t)$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$
>   $4.x(t)$ is bounded on $[0,\infty )$.

Utilizing the given equations,I see that $\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}-A\frac {dx}{dt}-Bx=0$ and $\frac {d^2y}{dt^2}-A\frac {dy}{dt}-By=0$.Do I have to solve it to reach a decision ? In that case ,it will be bit lengthy for a multiple choice question like it. Or are there any other better way to approach the problem? I am also not sure about the importance of $B<-1<A<0.$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the solutuons of the equation $\lambda^2-A \lambda -B = 0$. The solutions are $\frac{1}{2} (A \pm \sqrt{A^2+4B})$. Since $A^2<1$ and $4B<-4$, we see that the solutions have the form $\frac{1}{2} (A \pm i\sqrt{|A^2+4B|})$. Since $A<0$, the solutions decay as $e^{At}$ as $t \to \infty$, hence 4) is true. (The solutions blow up as $t \to -\infty$, of course.)